# How to set the fallback locale?

Tags: java, android, multilingual

I have several version of an app in one project.
For one version, if the locale of the device is not found (for example, no values-fr for a device in French), I'd like German to be used.
For another version, if the locale of the device is not found, I'd like English to be used.

Is there a way to accomplished this other than by overriding the values/strings.xml (which is used as the fallback resource) in each version?

Comment: Simply save a value in your preferences. Depending on that value, change the language on next start.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can choose a fallback locale for a specific locale that isn't found.

Instead you create a default locale that will always be used for fallback in the values/string.xml.

If the device is set to a locale that your app doesn't have (e.g. values-fr), it will then just use the default values string.xml.

Comment: ok that's a pity. Maybe using the current country official language would be a better solution (Google if your read this ^^).

We'll have to live with it or maybe override the default strings.xml in the gradle build script.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if you feel this is correct :)

Answer (score 0):

If there are untranslated resources, they'll fall back to the default file (the file that isn't set with a specific locale). You cannot change that behavior.

However, you can write a library for it, but since it is a library all references to `Context#getString` would call the native system which calls the default file and not a specific locale for fallback resources.

Comment: In my case where i wanted to show different strings as per locale. i have string in default, en-AU, en-TH. When app is running for en-US, string is picked from default (which is expected) but when app is running for en-CA, string is picked from en-AU (Android 9,10,11,12) and picked form en-TH (Android 13). Don't you think it is strange.